# C fgets giving unexpected result

Tags: c, loops, fgets

I'm doing Advent of Code 2022, and I'm hitting a strange bug for day 1 (https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1) which I need help with please.

Currently, I'm trying to parse a text file which has groups of numbers (https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1/input) and output the results to the screen. Code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define IN_FILE "input.txt"
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 20480

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Variable declaration
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    int counter = 0;
    int elfno = 0;
    FILE *fd;

    // Create "Key Value pair" struct. Use ints for both vars as we need to perform arithmetic on the values.
    struct kv_store
    {
        int key;
        int value;
    };

    struct kv_store kv[counter];
    //struct kv_store kv_total;

    // Open file

    fd = fopen(IN_FILE, "r");
    if (fd == NULL)
    {
        // File does not exist. Exit
        fprintf(stdout, "\n[*]%s not found in current working directory.", IN_FILE);
        return -1;
    }

    // Iterate through file line by line. Place lines into kv[n].value with kv[n].key as the elf number (elfno). Increment elfno once a blank line is found.
    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fd) != NULL)
    {
        if(strlen(line) == 1)
        {
            elfno ++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            kv[counter].key = elfno;
            sscanf(line, "%d", &kv[counter].value);
            //kv[counter].value = strtol(line, NULL, 0);
            counter ++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i < counter;i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Iteration: %d - Elf: %d holds: %d \n", i, kv[i].key, kv[i].value);
    }

    // TODO: Upon EOF, we can iterate through kv. If elfno for next value in kv hasn't changed, add value to kv_total[elfno].value. If it does change, move on to the next efls values.

    // TODO: Once complete, iterate through kv_total and find the largest number, print to screen.
    return 0;
}
```

Everything seems to be working ok, however on the 4th iteration of the while loop which reads the value **6086** from the input, I get a garbage result. I should be seeing **Elf: 1 holds: 6086**. The remaining iterations give the correct output (sample screenshot below).

[image]

Using my very limited knowledge of gdb and debugging, I've looked at the **line** variable during runtime and can see that the variable is being modified only when **line** contains the value **6086** partway through the iteration (screenshot below).

[image]

Checks carried out so far:

- Used a hex editor to confirm there is no rogue encoding within the input file
- Tried using `strtol` instead of of `sscanf`
- Tried to use `malloc()` and `free()` to clear the **line** variable at the end of each iteration

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: C doesn't have dynamic arrays. When you declare the array `kv` the value of `counter` is zero, so you will have a zero-sized array. And zero-sized arrays are invalid. When you use the array you will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*. Either use a fixed-size and make sure your code stops when you reach the limit. Or use dynamic allocation and *reallocation*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you put that as an answer please and I'll give the green tick? Didn't cross my mind at all that I was making it a zero-sized array. Thanks!

Comment: @tyrone1988 You can also post your own answer.

Comment: O.T. `fd` (file descriptor)  in `fd = fopen(IN_FILE, "r");` is a bad name, consider `fp` (file pointer)

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745578/c-fgets-giving-unexpected-result#comment131918825_74745578), you have a zero-length array:

```c
// ...
    int counter = 0;
    // ...
    struct kv_store kv[counter];
// ...
```

Accessing this will cause undefined behavior. Valgrind might be a useful tool for detecting this:

```
$ gcc aoc.c -ggdb3 -Wall && valgrind ./a.out
==58338== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==58338== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==58338== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==58338== Command: ./a.out
==58338== 
==58338== Invalid write of size 4
==58338==    at 0x109390: main (aoc.c:45)
==58338==  Address 0x1fff002a48 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Where `aoc.c:45` (line 45) is the first write to `kv`: `kv[counter].key = elfno;`.

Taking a step back, do you even need an array? The problem asks for a *maximum* of all elf loads. A greedy algorithm should work--whenever a larger load is found, that's the new best result globally. No need to store history since there is no chance of any other previous result usurping the current best.

If this isn't yet clear, a classic problem solving strategy is to simplify the problem and extrapolate from the solution to the simpler problem back to the larger problem. The problem can be simplified to finding the largest element in an array.

How would you solve that in your head in a real-life situation? You'd probably keep a "largest so far" number in your memory, then replace it whenever you find a larger number. There's no need to remember numbers that have been replaced since they're guaranteed to be sub-optimal. In time complexity terms, this entails O(1) space rather than O(n) (storing results in direct proportion to the size of the input).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int nums_len = 5;
    int nums[] = {3, 5, 6, 1, 3};
    int largest = nums[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums_len; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > largest) {
            largest = nums[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", largest); // => 6
}
```

The problem you're working on is similar, except there's the need to keep the total of the current chunk as you build it up, which can be accumulated on a single integer. Once the current chunk total has been compared against the overall largest chunk size, it can be thrown out, just like in the simpler problem.

Pseudocode:

```
largest = -infinity
current_chunk = 0

for (line in file) {
   if line is empty {
       largest = max(largest, current_chunk)
       current_chunk = 0 // prepare for the next chunk
   }
   else { // accumulate the size of the current chunk
       current_chunk += parse_integer(line)
   }
}

// current_chunk may still hold a value from the last
// chunk in the file, if the file doesn't end in a blank
// line, so consider it as a possible result one more time
largest = max(largest, current_chunk)

print largest
```

Try coding this in C.